# specify span on hovering link using jquery

Tags: jquery, hover, html

I'm trying to specify a span to show over a link when hovered. The code I have below does this, but it does so for all links containing a span, not just the hovered item. I was wondering how I can be more specific with the code. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
            $('ul#portfolio a').hover(function() {


                $('ul#portfolio a span').fadeIn();}, function() { $('ul#portfolio a span').fadeOut();


            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
$(this).find('span').fadeIn();

// ...

$(this).find('span').fadeOut();
```

Here `this` represents the `a` element that received the event. `$(this)` wraps it in a jQuery object, and the [`find()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/find/) method locates the nested `span` element.

Full code is:

```
$('ul#portfolio a').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('span').fadeIn();
}, function() { 
    $(this).find('span').fadeOut();
});
```

Be aware that the [`fadeOut()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) method does more than just set the opacity. It also hides the element after the animation is done.

You may want to use the [`fadeTo()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/) method instead:

```
$('ul#portfolio a').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('span').fadeTo( 600, 1 );
}, function() { 
    $(this).find('span').fadeTo( 600, 0 );
});
```

...or you could even do it like this:

```
$('img').hover(function( e ) {
    $(this).fadeTo(600, e.type === 'mouseenter');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('ul#portfolio a').hover(function() {
    $('span',$(this)).fadeIn();
}, function() {
    $('span',$(this)).fadeOut();
});
```